Number of solutions $x^2-dy^2=b$ in finite field $F$ with $char~F\neq 2$
Let $F$ be a finite field with $char~F\neq 2$. And $d$ a non-square in $F$.
If $b$ is $0$, then $x^2=dy^2$, the only solution is $x=y=0$.
If $b$ is non-zero, then it is said that the number of solution is $q+1$, where $q=|F|$.
I can not see why.
Thanks in advance.

I find a way.
Extend the field to $E=F[\sqrt{q}]$.
Then $x^2-dy^2=b$ iff $N(x+\sqrt{d}y)=(x+\sqrt{d}y)(x-\sqrt{d}y)=b$, where we consider the norm of $E/F$.
Now we know that the norm operator is surjective from $E^*$ to $F^*$, then the number of solution is $|E^*/F^*|=(q^2-1)/(q-1)=q+1$.

There is a whole book about finite fields and counting, author  Charles Small. See if I can find it. Alright, called Arithmetic of Finite Fields, published 1991.

@WillJagy Thanks. I will try to search the book.

When there is a single solution to this equation, it
being a curve of degree 2, using the birational correspondence  between a line and this curve by projection can get more solutions. A projective line over a field of $q$ points  has $q+1$ points.
